# Connecting the server using Mac Terminal

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, server, terminal, key

I would like to ask you what should I improve in the bash code to connect to the server. I am a beginner in bash, so would appreciate your help. As I am using Mac OSX, my teacher recommended also to use chmod 600 but I am not sure on which stage. democceng.pem is a key in text file downloaded from AWS Amazon.

```
cezarys-macbook-pro:~ cezaryrosa$ sh -i chmod 600 Downloads/democceng.pem.txt ubuntu@ec2-100-26-98-97.compute-1.amazonaws.com
sh: /bin/chmod: cannot execute binary file
cezarys-macbook-pro:~ cezaryrosa$
```

```
cezarys-macbook-pro:~ cezaryrosa$ sh -i Downloads/democceng.pem.txt ubuntu@ec2-100-26-98-97.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Downloads/democceng.pem.txt: line 1: -----BEGIN: command not found
: command not found.pem.txt: line 2: MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAi0bA7TW0UBd6Tz6YaFwaNr2jFVf9P+yrLUOh6Yd+pjLBddIS
: No such file or directory: line 3: 146fz5exj/2vOL+EziH2HAoeBwPnHRnYu/bhUj7BBR1ZqGEFqTiSXNW8jHE97PEQ
: No such file or directory: line 4: GjwNICy1vHQsIorygAuRVpQHIWujfb5mChcAwdOKXCPWSSrElY3xBeQz/9CHdDba
: No such file or directory: line 5: sMcUwBoHsAHCezb8wh3OnoJr5swzHCCEzP1ZJYH5I5MvaBsL5nwCPAyiX1fqMC/Y
: No such file or directory: line 6: zRQqva30VSWQPIqUYlO3G97x+KN/fLNaFR6e2Rm0wVdSFB9+NFxY9QZQJCIl6ujp
: command not found.pem.txt: line 7: sdrhzecdIFqbrCl+519vaUTof07aJ5+6VPzbeQIDAQABAoIBABKQMKCtOsY+CthL
: No such file or directory: line 8: EIdAV2IaboUmwCNoCPy0ef0lSRUfyLdKc6Z1ZQmHP2xgtJ0MscfDsQjVtGDc/U3c
: No such file or directory: line 9: pw2Of0O2B4YF/nA51kZSuvdSqZnSch2Fl87XWCyEqQhgN423FVFJuWpfun+S2Cyn
: No such file or directory: line 10: VvRbUoeDCXr0b9g6sg745zoQy3l5/xLC6Uclhw8J2Gz00qHIw6j3fb2bQsHBUrDJ
: No such file or directory: line 11: 2rnYqrhdzwEfWGUzQ0dIc3Puh9uLexLpgn/NKz1YQykZzDJMJh1/OxKpM28mvbec
: No such file or directory: line 12: ryJSc28bJ/h26Adu/9cG1AZulwWo0tIlACw6EVq/7KqdExp/0Ou0iJkyBln+bRGq
: No such file or directory: line 13: IUnRsQ0CgYEA7gvHvY7ig5G+/3tllEt7QlXdBOXs4HeQD53Siv2xdcmAFfUCv1ma
: command not found.pem.txt: line 14: ujxTjKdUAr8zbxtubbgBlIbghis8suM9KVOxVZy3BuiktoiKBFqVR42dVrFHAj8h
: command not found.pem.txt: line 15: 2af7ogeXclw2hOVlF+3B777wIASrVtazcSs5TAaFd8UluScmAUNBNU8CgYEAlcfq
: No such file or directory: line 16: /rWql1GsfjPtwUMuiqFiB/eQ0MZ7DGzZyUkWHyy/lVBu7JjXlRXA3Y1lEwkrlZe+
: command not found.pem.txt: line 17: ELBw1o7bP6RqbIM7LUmes2J8O5a+1xHPC9g1LWX2XzADKuyNl7YBBkFDcuO81x+4
: No such file or directory: line 18: kDpf/7iWd6BlZKyUZ173rVfxxj7e+rlIMeA0QLcCgYEAjd4zckN/t83auMQ/67t4
: No such file or directory: line 19: gDZP/KVTIQvgrY3vdqpvYrVuQqe8tXGfhzKA0KjApspwytzcWUN6nZwsn4mRKUPI
: No such file or directory: line 20: paKdY1p8sf9gevCw4JtjsDsz9AC/QxWBBQjaLNy9Y4iVbWqRb0thc5Kl5U8jFiPq
: No such file or directory: line 21: 2Z1bDnYsgQ7bxpcQTVxZtn0CgYBa5YQ7J0xroGkp/aGf04F/KAkyBI+h45HxLG3O
: command not found.pem.txt: line 22: tcfzC1kI6FMoymiqVRVCXvij4MDOe9QglLMlwnRT3xem2s0i4rao7m+uSgFuy6P2
: No such file or directory: line 23: 8DL1ZhdqFN0XQ496Lj3Y6epg4sxLUTjUblir+/10g6aEvichxIRScjiLssPnLGIf
: command not found.pem.txt: line 24: woxzaQKBgDsvFbHj9v9oLzdKdPMRaRSxtQZMR1APCPtDeUavHMjD5fUn1vAZ7mg3
: No such file or directory: line 25: iaMukEYk/7H/0WSEcUhDXCf8TeE85FSjZRT8HTxQrH8D0UZGM0+rz4uAqRXB0ecv
: command not found.pem.txt: line 26: L8o4XO2X6smDPqsgoB5MSINVV3RPEnInrRYK9lpmA0tTN1mpMqHe
Downloads/democceng.pem.txt: line 27: -----END: command not found
```

Comment: Not sure if it will get you all the way but first thing to fix is to use -i rather than i-

Comment: man ssh in terminal will show you available documentation

Comment: I have corrected it. As you can see Permission is denied. What should I focus on to make that it will work?

Comment: The first error is telling you what is wrong. File not found. Note that you need to use / not \ on mac. When you are typing in the command, use double tab to autocomplete directory/filename then you will know the path is correct

Comment: Really worth digging out a bash tutorial before trying anything too involved

Comment: Don’t use backslash in Mac paths, that’s Windows syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. So I made improvements with forward slash and double tab. As you can see it the first code chmod 600 does not execute the key. In the second code the key is visible but it does not lead to connect to the server.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are wanting to login to a remote server using SSH (not SH).

The keypair on the disk needs to have restricted permissions, so you can run this command:

```
chmod 600 Downloads/democceng.pem.txt
```

You only need to run that once, not every time you need to connect.

Then, to connect to the remote server, use:

```
ssh -i Downloads/democceng.pem.txt ubuntu@ec2-100-26-98-97.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```